How can I make these buttons to not overlap each other?
I want to make multiple buttons (ipsum-buttons) spread across the screen in random positions, but without overlapping each other.

Currently, I'm calculating the button positions using a polar coordinate system:
const generatePosition = (name: string, index: number) => {
    const hash = Array.from(name).reduce((acc, char) => acc + char.charCodeAt(0), 0) + index;
    const angle = (hash % 360) * (Math.PI / 180); // Convert hash to angle (radians)
    const radius = 35 + (hash % 15); // Radius between 35% and 50% of the area
    const x = 50 + radius * Math.cos(angle); // Map to x coordinate
    const y = 50 + radius * Math.sin(angle); // Map to y coordinate
    return { x, y };
};

CSS:
.ipsum-button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0.8rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

React code:
        {ipsumButtons.map((button) => (
          <button
            key={button.name}
            className={`${styles['ipsum-button']} ${selectedipsums.includes(button.name) ? styles['active-ipsum'] : ''}`}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: button.color,
              top: `${button.position.y}%`,
              left: `${button.position.x}%`,
            }}
            onClick={() => toggleipsumSelection(button.name)}
          >
            {button.name}
          </button>
        ))}

I'm stuck in this problem for weeks. How can I make sure these buttons don’t overlap each other?
EDIT: the reason I chose to use polar coordinates for positioning the buttons is to achieve a more effective and organized distribution of the buttons while keeping a central area empty. This approach has some distinct advantages, particularly when creating a layout that involves spacing elements in a circular pattern around a focal point.


The above seems to be a bit more difficult based on the deterministic approach of how the position is calculated. Meaning generating a hash value based on name and index. I would modify the function to give a more random position taking also into account the size of each button so they won't overlap.
component that renders the buttons:
const Component = () => {
    const [buttons, setButtons] = useState<ButtonData[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const height = window.innerHeight;
        const buttonData = generateButtonData(50, width, height); // Generate 10 buttons
        setButtons(buttonData);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='playground-wrapper'>
            {buttons.map(button => (
                <button
                    className='ipsum-button'
                    key={button.id}
                    style={{ left: button.x, top: button.y, background: button.color }}
                >
                    {button.label}
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

generateButtonData function:
const generateButtonData = (numButtons: number, width: number, height: number): ButtonData[] => {
    const buttonData: ButtonData[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {
        const { x, y } = generatePosition(buttonData, width, height);
        const color = getRandomColor();
        buttonData.push({ id: i, label: `Button ${i + 1}`, x, y, color });
    }
    return buttonData;
};

generatePosition function:
/**
 * Generates a random position for a button ensuring it does not overlap with existing buttons.
 *
 * @param {ButtonData[]} existingPositions - Array of existing button positions.
 * @param {number} width - The width of the container area.
 * @param {number} height - The height of the container area.
 * @returns {{ x: number, y: number }} - The generated x and y coordinates for the new button.
 */
const generatePosition = (existingPositions: ButtonData[], width: number, height: number): { x: number, y: number } => {
    let x, y;
    let overlap;
    const buttonSize = 100; // Updated button size to 100x100 pixels
    const buffer = 10; // Buffer zone around each button

    do {
        overlap = false;
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - buttonSize));
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - buttonSize));

        for (let pos of existingPositions) {
            if (Math.abs(pos.x - x) < buttonSize + buffer && Math.abs(pos.y - y) < buttonSize + buffer) {
                overlap = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (overlap);

    return { x, y };
};

I have also used a function to generate random colors as the initial array of data was not provided.
const getRandomColor = (): string => {
    const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let color = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
};


I just edited my question explaining why I chose to use polar coordinates.
